# AngularJS ngInit with Date

Tags: angularjs, date, angularjs-ng-init

I'm coding in .NET MVC and would like to pass a stored DateTime object to the front-end as an initial value for a Date object in a controller.

Here's what I've tried:

```
ng-init="params.datetime = new Date()"
```

This doesn't seem to work, and I'm getting a syntax error.

How can I pass in a Date object as an initial property for a scope variable?

http://jsfiddle.net/xX8LJ/

UPDATE

I forgot to include the Razor code in my code sample.

```
ng-init="params.datetime = new Date('@Model.DepartureTime.ToString("s")')"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Angular scope doesn't know about `Date`

Try to use:

```
 $scope.Date = new Date();
```

and after:

```
<div ng-controller="myController"
     ng-init="params.datetime = Date"
 >Current time: {{params.datetime}}</div>
```

Demo 1 <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xX8LJ/1/)**</kbd>

As an answer for your EDIT,

rewrite `Date` as method:

```
$scope.Date = function(arg){
   return new Date(arg);
};
```

and:

```
 <div ng-controller="myController" 
      ng-init="params.datetime = Date('Tue Feb 18 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)')"
  >Current time: {{params.datetime}}</div>
```

Demo 2 <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xX8LJ/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Awesome, this is just what I needed. Thanks! I found it a bit strange that ``ng-init="new Date()"`` doesn't work. Any ideas why Angular wouldn't know about the JS Date object?

Comment: @DzulqarnainNasir angular expressions do not support all of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it, in my case I've added a now function in my $rootScope in a config block:

```
...
$rootScope.now = now;

/**
* returns now as a date
* 
* @function 
* @param arg {object} date arguments
* @returns {Date} now
*/
function now(arg) {
    return new Date(arg);
}
...
```

and then can be used like this:

```
<div ng-init="product.date = $root.now();"...
```

or just

```
<div ng-init="product.date = now();"...
```

but I prefer using $root so we know exactly where the `now` function is located